# Fetch join causes N+1 queries or throws org.hibernate.QueryException

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I am trying to fetch with one query list of objects and its associations, unfortuantely, either I cause N+1 requests to database, or get hit with exception "org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list".

Please let me walk you through my case.

Below is my Data Model:

```
@Table(name = "first_table")
public class FirstObject {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "first_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "first_param")
    private String param1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "second_id")
    private SecondObject second;

    ...other columns...
}

@Table(name = "second_table")
public class SecondObject {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "second_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "second_param")
    private Long param2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "third_id")
    private ThirdObject third;

    ...other columns...
}

@Table(name = "third_table")
public class ThirdObject {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "third_id")
    private Long id;

    ...other columns...
}
```

It is true to database relations, also exactly how I want it on FE. 
All I am trying to achieve is to fetch all the associations with one query, giving 2 conditions:

```
ConditionBuilder condition = new ConditionBuilder()
            .and(FirstObject.second.param2.eq(some_number))
            .and(FirstObject.param1.eq(some_string));

    return from(FirstObject)
            .join(FirstObject.second).fetchJoin()
            .join(FirstObject.second.third).fetchJoin()
            .where(condition.generate())
            .fetch();
```

Unfortunately this code throws exception:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the
>   owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

I can make it work, but with N+1 queries, but it is acceptable only for development phase, as will cause performance issue.

```
...
.join(FirstObject.second).fetchJoin()
.join(FirstObject.second.third)
...
```

same here:

```
...
.join(FirstObject.second)
.join(FirstObject.second.third)
...
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to make hibernate to create one simple query like that:

```
select
    *
from
    first_table table1 
inner join
    second_table table2 
        on table1.second_id=table2.second_id 
inner join
    third_table table3 
        on table2.third_id=table3.third_id 
where
    table1.first_param="some_string"
    table2.second_param=some_number
```

All the help is very much appreciated, I've been fighting this for some time now, and really counting on community. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know the API you are using, but a fetch join is one way to fix this using direct HQL.  Another possibility would be to just do a raw SQL query containing the SQL you showed at the end of your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen last resort, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be mapping both sides of the entity relationship:

for instance, in `FirstObject` you have this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "second_id")
private SecondObject second;
```

So in `SecondObject` you should have this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "second") // this is the name of the field in the class that defines the join relationship
Collection<FirstObject> firstObjects;
```

In `ThirdObject` you should have this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "third") // this is the name of the field in the class that defines the join relationship
Collection<SecondObject> secondObjects;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. All results stayed the same.